# How to convert string (containing double max) to double

Tags: c++, string, double

I have no problem converting "normal" double values, but I can't convert `numeric_limits<double>::max(`) or `DBL_MAX` string representations?

```
std::string max = "1.79769313486232e+308";

std::istringstream stream(max);
double value;

// enters here, failbit is set
if (!(stream >> value))
```

Comment: Note that you need 17 decimal digits to uniquely determine a double, not 15.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could it be something like the actual value of `DBL_MAX` isn't exactly representable in exponential notation with 16 decimal places (say the decimal value is *very slightly* larger than the two based represenation) but initializing a `double` with the `DBL_MAX` will nevertheless set the correct value (due to rounding). `std::istringstream` may be a little bit more pickish.

**EDIT:** Actually I found that the value of `DBL_MAX` in my compiler is 1.7976931348623158e+308 which works fine for me to stream. Your number is rounded and slightly larger, hence the failure.

**EDIT2:** The exact value of `DBL_MAX` in decimal form is given by `(2 ^ (1023 - 52)) * (2 ^ 53 - 1)` which isn't representable with 16 decimal places.

Comment: Yep ... I checked, and I was about to answer the same thing! You got to be really careful with these things ...

Comment: You are right, for some reason my value was wrong. DBL_MAX is 1.7976931348623158e+308

Comment: "the actual value of DBL_MAX isn't exactly representable". The actual value of DBL_MAX is an integer, it's exactly representable in any base. Just not necessarily representable in exponential notation with 16 decimal places. So we know what you mean, but it's not quite what you said ;-)

Comment: @Steve Yeah, that's what I meant, I stole your line from the comment and updated the answer, hope you dont mind ;)

Answer (score 1):

if you use

```
double v = 1.79769313486232e+308;
cout << v << endl;
```

it would give you inf. that means the literal number is actually exceeds double now.